# SSAS : Unoknow Members still shows on Report Slicer

Tags: ssas

I have created Dimension - Vendors,Distributors and Time
And I have Fact tables Purchase and Total Paid Amount.
I have also set below properties for Dimension :

UnknownMember : Hidden
and for the Key Column Property
NullProcess : Error

I have also done properly Attribute Relationship on the Cube. So that it is giving me proper result as below.

[image]

It is showing values without Unknown Members.

Now, On my report I have put the slicer for the Venders.

And it still shows Unknown as a member. I don't even have any null key in any table.

[image]

Anyone has any idea, how to get rid of this unknown member with Best Practices?
I am using SQL Server 2012 with Latest NU update. So that I can create Power View reports using connection on sharepoint site.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you deployed and processed your cube since you changed the vendor dimension to have the unknown member be hidden? If the unknown member were not hidden, it would make sense that it shows up in the slicer and not in the table.  The slicer shows all possible values where the table is probably showing no-empty values.

Comment: Yes, I did Process and Deploy after setting these properties. But still shows in Slicer . Is there any way to hide them in Slicer? Thank you for your response